# Obtain CRS from existing axis with cartopy

Tags: python, coordinate-system, matplotlib, cartopy

Is there a method to get the CRS from a figure created with cartopy?
Say for example, I only had access to the `ax` created here:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like `ax.get_crs()` to return `'PlateCarree'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using following function I speed up my search.

```
import re

def getPat2(keyword, L):
     
    list = [ item for item in L if re.search(keyword, item) is not None ]

    return list  #return results
```

So, I ran your code lines:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

and afterward, I ran my function with:

```
>>>L = dir(ax)
>>>getPat2('crs', L)
[]  #not results
>>>getPat2('proj', L)
['projection']
```

So, method is 'projection'; not 'get_crs'.

Running my function again but with **dir(ax.projection)**:

```
>>>M = dir(ax.projection)
>>>getPat2('proj', M)
['_project_line_string', '_project_linear_ring', '_project_multiline', '_project_multipoint', '_project_multipolygon', '_project_point', '_project_polygon', 'proj4_init', 'proj4_params', 'project_geometry']
```

With following command lines you can get proj4 parameters and project geometry.

```
>>>ax.projection.proj4_params
{'ellps': 'WGS84', 'a': 57.29577951308232, 'proj': 'eqc', 'lon_0': 0.0}
>>>ax.projection.proj4_init
'+ellps=WGS84 +a=57.29577951308232 +proj=eqc +lon_0=0.0 +no_defs'
>>>ax.projection.project_geometry
<bound method Projection.project_geometry of <cartopy.crs.PlateCarree object at 0x7f6274275678
```

You can use above function for exploring other 'methods' where explicitly also appears 'PlateCarree'.

Comment: That's a bit of a rough solution, but thanks it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but just use

```
crs_ax = ax.projection
```